# Xpages Extension Library Namepicker error

Tags: xpages, xpages-extlib

I recently upgraded to the latest version of the extension library on the 9.0.1 Domino server and Designer client (901v00_06.20140424-0600).

I am now getting the following error on an XPage when I click on the namepicker control.

RequestError: Unable to load /dbname.nsf/log.xsp?$$viewid=!ds0dulblv5!&$$axtarget=view:_id1:_id2:_id10:tabPanel1:namePicker1&count=50 status: 500

(dbname has been stripped out)

This is the source for my namepicker control:

```
<xe:namePicker id="namePicker1" for="name1" dialogTitle="Domino Directory">
<xe:this.dataProvider>
<xe:dominoNABNamePicker
addressBookDb="server!!names.nsf"
addressBookSel="db-name" people="true" groups="false"
nameList="people">
</xe:dominoNABNamePicker>
</xe:this.dataProvider>    
</xe:namePicker>
```

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Dan

PS:

addressBookDb="server!!names.nsf" <--- server name stripped out.

Comment: Check the XPages log files on the server in order to find the error message behind the error 500 that you are experiencing. Use XPages Log File Reader for easy access to the XPages log files

Comment: Thanks Per. Turns out the error had nothing to do with the namepicker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was linked to some incomplete javascript on the XPage and had nothing to do with the namepicker.